# Futter mouse animation

Tags: flutter

i was wondered how to implement this cool web animation using flutter framwork and dart language.

[Sample](https://www.veed.io/view/b02bf4c8-a934-40f0-a5fb-0904cb435aba?sharingWidget=true&panel=share)

i tried to do this :

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Offset _offset = Offset.zero;
  double x = 0;
  double y = 0;
  double z = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MouseRegion(
      cursor: SystemMouseCursors.cell,
      onExit: (event) {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        setState(() {});
      },
      onHover: (details) {
        setState(() {
          _offset = details.delta;
          y = y - details.delta.dx / 100;
          x = x + details.delta.dy / 100;
        });
      },
      child: Transform(
        // offset: _offset,
        transform: Matrix4.identity()
          // Matrix4(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
          ..rotateX(x)
          ..rotateY(y)
          ..rotateZ(z)
          ..setEntry(2, 2, 0.002),
        alignment: FractionalOffset.center,

        child: Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but this does not give me the same behavior of animation on enter the mouse region from any position .

Answer (score 1):

You can use some external packages to get this hover effect :

[motion package](https://pub.dev/packages/motion)

From the README, you only need to add :

```
import 'package:motion/motion.dart';

...

return Motion(child: myWidget);
```

You also have some options to customize the effect.

Comment: wow ,it is really the same behavior that i want but what if i am want to learn how to implement it from scratch so that know something new?

Comment: If you want to know more about this package, you can check the Github repository: https://github.com/mrcendre/motion/tree/main/motion/lib